# RichTextBoxで行ごとに背景色を指定したい

Tags: vb.net, winforms

お世話になります。
表題の通りなのですがリッチテキストコントロール(winForm)で行毎に背景色を設定したいのですがどのような方法が考えられますでしょうか？

イメージとしてはSyntaxHighlighterのようなイメージです。

RichTextBox.SelectionBackColorを使って出来るかなとも考えましたが改行記号までしか選択出来ないと考えておりますので一行すべての色を変える訳には行かないと見ております。

ご存知の方おられましたらよろしくお願いします。

[image: 画面イメージ]

開発環境
Windows10
VB.NET(.NetFramework4.0)
WinFormアプリケーション

Answer (score 1, accepted):

背景を透過させて、行ごとに背景を描画

vb

```
Friend Class RichTextBoxEx
    Inherits RichTextBox

    Private Const WM_PAINT As Integer = 15

    Private Const WS_EX_TRANSPARENT As Integer = 32

    Private Gray As Brush = New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 240, 240, 240))

    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams As CreateParams
        Get
            Dim parms As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            parms.ExStyle = parms.ExStyle Or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            Return parms
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        If m.Msg = WM_PAINT Then
            Invalidate()
            Using graphic As Graphics = MyBase.CreateGraphics()
                Dim pevent = New PaintEventArgs(graphic, Me.ClientRectangle)
                OnPaintBackground(pevent)
            End Using

            MyBase.WndProc(m)
        Else
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(ByVal pevent As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaintBackground(pevent)
        Dim topleftIndex = Me.GetCharIndexFromPosition(Me.ClientRectangle.Location)
        Dim topleftLine = Me.GetLineFromCharIndex(topleftIndex)
        Dim linefirstIndex As Integer = GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(topleftLine)
        Dim p0 = Me.GetPositionFromCharIndex(topleftIndex)
        Dim lineCharIndexies As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)()
        lineCharIndexies.Add(0)
        Dim index As Integer = 0
        For Each s As String In Lines
            index += s.Length + 1
            lineCharIndexies.Add(index)
        Next

        Dim textLineIndex As Integer = lineCharIndexies.FindIndex(Function(i) i >= topleftIndex)

        Do While (textLineIndex < lineCharIndexies.Count - 1 AndAlso p0.Y < Me.ClientRectangle.Bottom)
            Dim nextLineCharIndex As Integer = lineCharIndexies(textLineIndex + 1)
            Dim nextLinePoint = GetPositionFromCharIndex(nextLineCharIndex)
            Dim h = nextLinePoint.Y - p0.Y
            If (textLineIndex Mod 2) = 0 Then
                Dim rect = New Rectangle(p0.X, p0.Y, Me.ClientRectangle.Width, h)
                pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(Gray, rect)
            End If

            p0.Y = nextLinePoint.Y
            textLineIndex += 1
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

c#

```
class RichTextBoxEx : RichTextBox
{
    private const int WM_PAINT = 15;
    private const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x20;
    private Brush Gray = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF,0xF0,0xF0,0xF0));

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams parms = base.CreateParams;
            parms.ExStyle |= WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
            return parms;
        }
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_PAINT)
        {
            Invalidate();
            using (Graphics graphic = base.CreateGraphics())
            {
                var pevent = new PaintEventArgs(graphic, this.ClientRectangle);
                OnPaintBackground(pevent);
            }

            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
        else
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        base.OnPaintBackground(pevent);
        var topleftIndex = this.GetCharIndexFromPosition(this.ClientRectangle.Location);
        var topleftLine = this.GetLineFromCharIndex(topleftIndex);
        int linefirstIndex = GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(topleftLine);
        var p0 = this.GetPositionFromCharIndex(topleftIndex);

        List<int> lineCharIndexies = new List<int>();
        lineCharIndexies.Add(0);
        int index = 0;
        foreach (string s in Lines)
        {
            index += s.Length + 1;
            lineCharIndexies.Add(index);
        }
        int textLineIndex = lineCharIndexies.FindIndex(_ => _ >= topleftIndex);

        for (; textLineIndex < lineCharIndexies.Count-1 && p0.Y < this.ClientRectangle.Bottom; textLineIndex++)
        {
            int nextLineCharIndex=lineCharIndexies[textLineIndex + 1];
            var nextLinePoint = GetPositionFromCharIndex(nextLineCharIndex);
            var h = nextLinePoint.Y - p0.Y;

            if ((textLineIndex % 2) == 0)
            {
                var rect = new Rectangle(p0.X, p0.Y, this.ClientRectangle.Width, h);
                pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(Gray, rect);
            }
            p0.Y = nextLinePoint.Y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @pulserさま サンプルコードありがとうございます。
現在VBに変換中ですが
    int textLineIndex = lineCharIndexies.FindIndex(_ => _ >= topleftIndex); 
の_ => _ >= topleftIndexが文法的にどのような意味なのか分かりません。教えて頂けますでしょうか？

Comment: c#と勘違いしていたのでvbのコードを追加しました。
vbだとfunction(n) n>=topleftIndexになり、各行のＹ座標でtopleftIndex以上か(つまり表示されている一番上の行が何行目か)を探すためのラムダ式になります。

Comment: さま、ご教示頂きありがとうございました。Subのオーバーライドなど非常に参考になりました。　今後はもっとリファレンスを熟読するように努めます。今回は真にありがとうございました。